# Нет кнопки "Искать" у поискового поля, но зачем-то есть кнопка задать вопрос?

Tags: дефект, дизайн, поиск

Нет кнопки <kbd>Искать</kbd> у поискового поля.

Мне её не хватает: перехожу на профиль пользователя, в строку поиска подставляется его id и я хочу выполнить такой поиск. Для всех перечисленных действий мне была нужна только мышь, а вот поиск без клавиатуры запустить не получается :(

А ещё не понимаю, зачем тут нужна кнопка задать вопрос.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Просто нажать Enter разве не срабатывает?

Comment: @AK, срабатывает, но на мыши у меня кнопки enter нет ;)

Comment: @Kromster, что-то ты слишком любишь мне заголовки менять.

Comment: Нет, не люблю, а что?

Comment: Текст в поиске набирать перед нажатием Enter мышой тоже как-то не очень.

Comment: @PashaPash, так я ж в вопросе написал - текст подставлен туда самим движком.